# What is the .NET equivalent to TApplication or how to call this Dll in .NET Managed Code?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, dllimport

Here is the cpp code to call the dll function"

```
typedef void (__stdcall *Terminal)(TApplication*, TFileStream *k, HANDLE N, int D);
```

Here is my C# code to call the function"

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern void terminal(IntPtr Application, IntPtr FileStream, IntPtr CommHandle, int mode);
```

and the function call:

```
terminal(IntPtr.Zero, FileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), CommHandle, 0);
```

if i call terminal with the Application ptr set to this.Handle i get a System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: When i call it with "IntPtr.Zero" the dll is able to create its window but then fails with Access violation at "0xXXXX" in module 'somedll.dll'. Read of Adress XXXXXXXXX.

Comment: There does not seem to be an equivalent.

Comment: If you have updates to make to your question then modify the question.  Using the comments to post "updates" will get confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a Delphi `TApplication` from .net. You can't create a Delphi `TFileStream` from .net. This DLL appears to be inaccessible from anything other than Delphi or C++ Builder.

The only way you could hope for it to work from .net would be if the DLL also exported functions that created instances of `TApplication` or `TFileStream`, which you could then pass on to the function in your question.

The `TApplication` class is a VCL class representing the application. It is the equivalent of the WinForms `Application` class. Likewise `TFileStream` is a VCL class wrapping file I/O in a stream-like interface. The .net `FileStream` class is similar. But you simply cannot synthesise working instances of Delphi/VCL classes from .net.

Comment: Agreed. Further investigation confirms this. I can launch the window with IntPtr.Zero as the TApplication* which works just fine, but when it tries to read from the TFileStream it is getting Access violation errors as would be expected.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the DLL? It's odd that someone would write a DLL that could only be consumed by Delphi hosts.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Its a dll compiled by C++/Delphi editor from this company: http://www.embarcadero.com/

Comment: @Ramhound How can you tell that?

Comment: Well, yes, @Ramhound. Of course it's *compiled* by that company; Embarcadero is the compiler vendor, and the compiler leaves its mark in everything it generates. Only a Delphi or C++ Builder compiler would be able to export a function that receives TApplication. The question is who the *DLL* vendor is.

Comment: Actually it was made by a friend who had a solution to a specific problem and didnt want to send me the source code. The TApplication turned out to not be the problem. It was the TFileStream. I mistakenly assumed it would accept a standard HANDLE. Doh. I was able to pass IntPtr.Zero for the TApplication Object and when the dll was recompiled to accept a char array for the file path everything worked. Poor programming by the dll creator and poor "eye lookin" by me.